# how to Sort an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Say that i have an array like this :

```
$arr_sequences = 
    array('00-02', '02-03', '03-07', '23-03', '03-23', '07-11', '11-10', '11-11');
```

How to sort the array so the values would look like this :

```
$arr_sequences = 
    array('00-02', '02-03', '03-23', '23-03', '03-07', '07-11', '11-11', '11-10');
```

If we look closely each value has an id (code) that's divided by `-`

For example :

```
$arr_sequences[2] = '03-07'; // '07' as last code, then search another value with '07' in front of the value
```

Then next index value shoud be

```
$arr_sequences[5] = '07-11'; // '07' front, then search '11' as next value
```

the goal is to sort the array without losing any length.

I have tried with tree algorithm, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What sort order is that? Can you post what you've tried.

Comment: I don't understand the relation between the elements here. Could you explain?

Comment: If you can explain the sorting then yes.  You can create custom sorting for arrays in javascript very easily.

Comment: sorry for short desciptions, if we look closely, each value has codes (divided by '-')..

each code is identifier to get next value, 
example :

1 => '03-23' next code should be '23-03', 
2 => '07-11' next code should be '11-11' then '11-07'

Comment: @KoujiAkira please update this question.

Comment: So, kind of like dominoes?

Comment: This might get quite complicated which makes it a good challenge/question, unfortunately the problem isn't described and there is no efforts showed.

Comment: This is not an exercise in sorting, but a problem in calculating linkages. The problem is complex, even in the example given, where at least three possible solutions exist, but in some not all elements are used. Is the set guaranteed to complete in it's entirety? How should we prioritise linkages (if they can be prioritised), or should the algorithm iterate over all possible solutions to find a complete one?

Comment: @FDL, hmm, maybe you can say it like that..

each link's "second code" is key to get next link

Comment: From your example, if there are 2 results with the key `11`, which should be chosen? Is there a priority (as Mike W asks) or should it test both to see which one 'works without losing length'?

Comment: Process the array once into an indexed array, which indexes items by their first part: `array('07' => '11', '03' => '42', ...)`. Pick one item to start with. Now easily look up the next item from the indexed array. Hope this gives you something to start. But indeed, this is a very complex problem unless it's guaranteed that all parts are unique.

Comment: **To all those who are close voting** : The question is clear enough now.

Comment: @FDL sadly, it has to be tested which one works without losing length..

Comment: You are solving dominoes. this has nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: @fsw hmm thanks ill keep it in mind, at first i think it was tree sort

Comment: "I have tried with tree algorithm, but I can't get it to work." - which algorithms were those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The crazy approach:**

1. Generate all possible permutations
2. Loop through each permutation and see if there is a domino effect and add it to the output

**The PHP code**

```
$arr_sequences = array('00-02', '02-03', '03-07', '23-03', '03-23', '07-11', '11-10', '11-11'); // Input

$permutations = permutations($arr_sequences); // Generating permutations

// Generating a regex
$n = count($arr_sequences);
$regex = '\d+';
for($i=1;$i<$n;$i++){
    $regex .= '-(\d+)-\\'.$i;
}
$regex .= '-\d+';

$sorted = preg_grep('#'.$regex.'#', $permutations); // Filtering the permutations
sort($sorted); // re-index the keys

//generating the desired output
$output = array();
foreach($sorted as $key => $sample){
    $temp = explode('-', $sample);
    $c = count($temp); // Micro-optimization, yeaaaah!
    for($i=0;$i<$c;$i+=2){
        $output[$key][] = $temp[$i] . '-' . $temp[$i+1];
    }
}

print_r($output); // printing

// Function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14998162
function permutations($elements) {
    if(count($elements)<2) return $elements;
    $newperms= array();
    foreach($elements as $key=>$element) {
        $newelements= $elements;
        unset($newelements[$key]);

        $perms= permutations($newelements);
        foreach($perms as $perm) {
            $newperms[]= $element."-".$perm;
        }
    }
    return $newperms;
}
```

**The output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00-02
            [1] => 02-03
            [2] => 03-23
            [3] => 23-03
            [4] => 03-07
            [5] => 07-11
            [6] => 11-11
            [7] => 11-10
        )

)
```

<sub>It seems that there was only one solution :p</sub>

Comment: wow, thanks hamza, thanks to all of you guys for your effort, but hamza answered first. i've tried it for about 3 days with no solution TT_TT

Comment: @KoujiAkira Zettai makeruna, gambatte~ :)

Answer (score 1):

A Brute Force way, in php.  (Not tested):

```
<?php

$arr = array('00-02', '02-03', '03-07', '23-03', '03-23', '07-11', '11-10', '11-11');

function findMatches($i, $val_ignore, $arr) {
    $arr_matches = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
      $j = substr_replace($val, '', 2);
      if (($i == $j) && ($val != $val_ignore))
        $arr_matches[] = $val;
    }
    return $arr_matches;
}

$arr_sorted = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    $i = substr_replace($val, '', 0, 3);
    if (!in_array($val, $arr_sorted)) $arr_sorted[] = $val;
    $arr_sorted = array_merge($arr_sorted, findMatches($i, $val, $arr));
}

?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work... `[2] => 03-07 [3] => 03-23 [4] => 07-11` ([3] is incorrect) [see example](http://codepad.org/UmiEFq4G).

Comment: yes, but still.. thanks for your effort stefan @_@ b

Comment: Thanks Kouji.. yes you are right, FDL.  Hope to figure this out later...